# Read a list of integers, find the line in a file with the same value at some indexes as items in the list, perform some arithmetic operations

Tags: python

I have a list of integers ([1, 3, 4]) and a formatted text file (test.pdb).
The test.pdb file:

```
ATOM      1  N   SER     1     -14.706 -29.806  -3.865  0.184900
ATOM      2  H1  SER     1     -15.618 -30.086  -3.533  0.189800
ATOM      3  H2  SER     1     -14.026 -30.040  -3.156  0.189800
ATOM      4  H3  SER     1     -14.488 -30.305  -4.715  0.189800
ATOM      5  CA  SER     1     -14.683 -28.336  -4.098  0.056700
ATOM      6  HA  SER     1     -13.688 -28.054  -4.442  0.078200
ATOM      7  CB  SER     1     -15.696 -27.936  -5.177  0.259600
ATOM      8  HB2 SER     1     -15.601 -28.601  -6.035  0.027300
ATOM      9  HB3 SER     1     -16.710 -28.024  -4.786  0.027300
ATOM     10  OG  SER     1     -15.483 -26.605  -5.613 -0.671400
ATOM     11  HG  SER     1     -15.151 -26.628  -6.513  0.423900
ATOM     12  C   SER     1     -14.965 -27.593  -2.793  0.616300
ATOM     13  O   SER     1     -15.470 -28.179  -1.836 -0.572200
ATOM     14  N   THR     2     -14.651 -26.302  -2.750 -0.415700
ATOM     15  H   THR     2     -14.216 -25.869  -3.552  0.271900
ATOM     16  CA  THR     2     -14.828 -25.492  -1.545 -0.038900
ATOM     17  HA  THR     2     -15.014 -26.146  -0.693  0.100700
ATOM     18  CB  THR     2     -13.536 -24.738  -1.255  0.365400
ATOM     19  HB  THR     2     -13.741 -23.919  -0.564  0.004300
ATOM     20  CG2 THR     2     -12.516 -25.669  -0.599 -0.243800
ATOM     21 1HG2 THR     2     -11.604 -25.109  -0.388  0.064200
ATOM     22 2HG2 THR     2     -12.911 -26.054   0.341  0.064200
ATOM     23 3HG2 THR     2     -12.279 -26.506  -1.256  0.064200
ATOM     24  OG1 THR     2     -13.004 -24.220  -2.475 -0.676100
ATOM     25  HG1 THR     2     -13.466 -23.394  -2.637  0.410200
ATOM     26  C   THR     2     -15.985 -24.509  -1.598  0.597300
ATOM     27  O   THR     2     -16.330 -23.881  -0.599 -0.567900
```

I want a Python code to do the following.

1. Read the first item on the list.
2. Locate the line in the text file with the same value at indexes 6-11 as the first item in the list (the second line in the test.pdb file).
3. Assign the indexes 30-38, 38-46, and 46-54 of that line (the second line of the file for the first item in the list) to variables *xl*, *yl*, and *zl*, respectively.
4. Read the file line by line.
5. Assign the indexes 30-38, 38-46, and 46-54 to the variables *xi*, *yi*, and *zi*, respectively.
6. Determine a standard deviation between *xi*, *yi*, & *zi*, and *x1*, *y1*, & *z1*, as follows.

   ```
           SD = ((xi - xl)**2 + (yi - yl)**2 + (zi - zl)**2)**0.5
   ```
7. If the *SD* value is greater than 2, do nothing, but if it is less than 6, store the 6-11 index of that line in a new list.
8. Similarly, repeat this process for the remaining integers on the original list.

I would appreciate your assistance in completing this task. The following is my primary code.

```
# The list
list = [1, 3, 4]
# REad the test.pdb file
pdb_text = open("test.pdb", "r")
data_pdb = pdb_text.read()
# Define the variables
xl = 0.00
yl = 0.00
zl = 0.00
xi = 0.00
yi = 0.00
zi = 0.00
SD = 0.00
# Define the new list
new_list = []
for item in list:
    for line in data_pdb.split('\n'):
        if int(item) == int(line[6:11]):
            xl = float(line[30:38])
            yl = float(line[38:46])
            zl = float(line[46:54])
            for lines in data_pdb.split('\n'):
                xi = float(lines[30:38])
                yi = float(lines[38:46])
                zi = float(lines[46:54])
                SD = ((xi - xl)**2 + (yi - yl)**2 + (zi - zl)**2)**0.5
                if SD <= 2:
                    mm = int(lines[6:11])
                    updated = new_list.append(mm)
            print(updated)
```

I expect an output like the following:
new_list =[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

Comment: the question lists 8 tasks, does your code accomplish any of the 8 tasks? what part are you stuck at? If you don't recieve a direct answer, Isolating specific problems you are having may get more helpful feedback

Comment: Yes, It accomplishes all tasks but does not update the list.

Comment: then you will probably want to write the result to a new list

Comment: new_list.append(mm) returns None

Comment: Task 7 makes no sense. If SD == 5 (for example) then it's both greater than 2 and less than 6

Answer (score 0):

A `list.append` operation does modify the list that is used, it doesn't return a new list. You only need to write `new_list.append(mm)` and at the end of all loops, do `print(new_list)`

Improvements

- variable naming, don't use `list` that is the list constructor
- better split on spaces and use indices rather than string indices, that handles an error in the file format

```
items = [1, 3, 4]
with open("test.pdb", "r") as pdb_text:
    data_pdb = pdb_text.read().splitlines()

results = []
for item in items:
    for line in data_pdb:
        line_parts = line.split()
        if item == int(line_parts[1]):
            xl, yl, zl = float(line_parts[5]), float(line_parts[6]), float(line_parts[7])
            for other_line in data_pdb:
                other_line_parts = other_line.split()
                xi, yi, zi = float(other_line_parts[5]), float(other_line_parts[6]), float(other_line_parts[7])
                SD = ((xi - xl) ** 2 + (yi - yl) ** 2 + (zi - zl) ** 2) ** 0.5
                if SD <= 2:
                    mm = int(other_line_parts[1])
                    results.append(mm)
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient approach using a data dictionary might be helpful. Something like this:

```
from math import sqrt

FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/test.pdb'

results = set()

def extract(line):
    _, i, _, _, _, *x, _ = line.split()
    return int(i), tuple(map(float, x))

items = [1, 3, 4]


with open(FILENAME) as pdb:
    data_dictionary = dict(map(extract, pdb))
    for item in items:
        xl, yl, zl = data_dictionary[item]
        for mm, (xi, yi, zi) in data_dictionary.items():
            if mm != item:
                SD = sqrt((xi - xl) ** 2 + (yi - yl) ** 2 + (zi - zl) ** 2)
                if 2 < SD < 6: # is SD relevant?
                    results.add(mm)

    print(results)
```

This does not produce the output suggested in the question. This is because the condition under which the standard deviation is considered relevant is ambiguous